# PageMethods is not defined, adding static breaks it

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am developing an ASP.Net application where I'm running into some trouble calling a function in the code behind using JavaScript.

This is the JavaScript function I'm trying to run:

```
PageMethods.EditRecord($(this).data("row-id"));
```

And this is my code behind function:

```
public void EditRecord(string logID)
{
    lblLogID.Text = logID;

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Show", "<script> $('#edit').modal('toggle');</script>");
}
```

If I run it like this I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: PageMethods is not defined

I did some reading and realized that I'm supposed to change `public void EditRecord(string logID)` to `public static void EditRecord(string logID)`.

Unfortunately, when I attempt that then `lblLogID` and `ClientScript` give me hassles with the following error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static, method, or property...

How can I work around this to run my code behind method using JavaScript without all these drawbacks?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775117/asp-net-scriptmanager-pagemethods-is-undefined

Comment: @HansKesting it's not a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a success callback function.

In your script,

`PageMethods.EditRecord($(this).data("row-id"), onSuccess);`

`function onSuccess(logId)
{ $("#"+"<%=lblLogId.ClientID%>").html(logId);
}`

In your aspx.cs,

`[WebMethod]
public static string EditRecord(string logID)
{
  return logID;
}`

Answered from mobile device.

Hope this helps you to implement.

Note: It has to be static. You cannot use ASP.net controls in your static method. All you can do is, return whatever you want from the method and use it in JavaScript.