# How to call C# code from javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

In my application I need to call aspx.cs method to bind Gridview from javascript function call how can i do this I searched and found some codes but it didn't work for me

I tried code:

Client Side:

```
<script>
 function MyHeader() {      

           PageMethods.BindHeaderGrid(); //I tried this one also
           var x = document.getElementById('HeaderDiv');
           if (x.style.display === 'none') {
               x.style.display = 'block';
               img2.src= "minus.gif";               

           } else {
               x.style.display = 'none';
               img2.src= "plus.gif";
           }      
       }       
</script>

<img id='img2' width="9px" border="0" src="plus.gif" onclick="MyHeader()"/> Header <div id="HeaderDiv" style="display:none">         
          <asp:GridView ID="GrdHeader" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
              <Columns>
                  <asp:BoundField  DataField="SenderID" HeaderText="SenderID" />
                  <asp:BoundField  DataField="ReceiverID" HeaderText="ReceiverID" />
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="Transactiondate" HeaderText="Transactiondate" />
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="RecordCount" HeaderText="RecordCount" />
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="DispositionFlag" HeaderText="DispositionFlag" />
              </Columns>
          </asp:GridView></div>
```

ServerSide: aspx.cs

```
[WebMethod]
    public void BindHeaderGrid()
    {        
        GrdHeader.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        GrdHeader.DataBind();

    }
```

Thank you

Comment: That's a wrong way of doing that. You cannot force a ASPX Datagrid to `Bind()` from Javascript. That would require **a postback**. I suggest you look into scriptmanager and updatepanel.

Comment: @uɐpuɐɥƆ, I don't want to call javascript function from codebehind. I need .cs method to call from javascript function.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089760/how-to-call-an-asp-net-c-sharp-method-using-javascript

Comment: @uɐpuɐɥƆ, I tried that one also but my function is not calling

Comment: Debug in both .cs and javascript and Mention what error you are getting

Comment: @KobyDouek, whatever your saying  I tried with this scriptmanager and updatepanel but it is not working

Comment: @uɐpuɐɥƆ, I am getting `PageMethods is undefined`

Comment: did you searched for that? if no, have a look into it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775117/asp-net-scriptmanager-pagemethods-is-undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this - Call a function in Server side from client side.

I seen your code and I have 2 options for you:

1. If you only want show or hide Gridview #GrdHeader then you can alway call "BindHeaderGrid" on page load (or the same)
2. If you want reload Gridview when user click to #img2 then you may by split GridView #GrdHeader to a page and embeaded it to this page by a iframe tag, when use click to img #img2 only reload the iframe tag

Comment: which your choice?

Comment: I need when i click image(+) i need to load and display gridview. when image (-) click hide gridview

Comment: ServerSide: aspx.cs

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                        
           if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
               BindHeaderGrid()
            }
            
        }

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

JavaScript

```
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {data: data}, // if no data available leave this out
                url: "example.asmx/exampleMethod", //if you wanna call a function in the page just include the function name in here
                success: function (data) {

                    // do something if the function is success

                }
            });
```

C# Webservice

```
 public class Example: System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public void exampleMethod(Parameters)
        {
            // Something you wanna do

           //If you wanna return something to javascript 
            Context.Response.ContentType = "text/HTML";
            var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(returnDataObject));
        }
}
```

In you case i think his might work.

```
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "BindHeaderGrid()", 
                success: function (data) {

                }
            });
```